# Integrating eclipse's hot deploy to also run unit test automatically, without performing maven install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have set up eclipse to work just as I want with my java web app using the following instructions : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189031/106261.

Is it also possible to get unit tests to be run as part of the auto build, without running a maven install (or test). So I make a change to a class, the tests get run, and if a fail occurs I get a some sort of indicator. Without needing to manually run `maven test`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run incremental/automated JUnit testing in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842042/is-it-possible-to-run-incremental-automated-junit-testing-in-eclipse)

Comment: It's not needed to do a mvn install to run unit test (mvn clean package will do the job).

Comment: @khmarbaise mvn clean doesn't, in my set up anyway. But the point of the question is without using maven at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, all with their own limitations:

1. You could set up a CI server which builds your project every time you commit a new version. Very reliable but not really "real time"
2. You can add your own builder to the list of builders (project properties -> Builders), for example an Ant builder which runs "ant test" or something. This builder gets invoked every time you save. **Every time**. That means Eclipse will become a total slug unless running your unit tests takes less than a few milliseconds.
3. You can use one of the plugins mentioned here: [Is it possible to run incremental/automated JUnit testing in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842042/is-it-possible-to-run-incremental-automated-junit-testing-in-eclipse)